# Process finished with exit code 139

Tags: c#, .net, отладка

В операционную систему Ubuntu установил Dotnet. Склонировал сначала свой проект, начал вываливаться. Потом создал проект из шаблона (Avalonia MVVM), сообщение:

> Process finished with exit code 139.

Та же участь постигает и консольное приложение `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");` - надпись в консоле не появляется, вместо неё та же ошибка 139.

Когда запускаю дебаггер, сообщение следующее:

> One or more errors occurred. (Started a process for debugging, but no CoreCLR runtime was seen to be loaded within the 00:00:16 time limit.)

На другой Ubuntu и в Windows подобная ситуация вообще не возникает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");` - весь мой код, на котором возникает ошибка

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin исправил

Answer (score 0):

SIGSEGV - Это ошибка по защите памяти. Т.е. ваша программа пытается обратиться к участку памяти, который ей не принадлежит. В 99% процентах случаев, такая ошибка возникает по двум причинам:

Индекс массива выходит за допустимый диапазон
Указатель получает некое "левое" (или вообще - никакого) значение.
У вас указателей нет, но есть два массива (вектора) с индексами которых далеко не всё очевидно.

Разбираться с ними глядя на код - скучно. Поэтому рекомендую скомпилировать Вашу программу с ключом -g и запустить под отладчиком gdb. Он Вам покажет конкретное место ошибки.

Comment: Но у меня нет в программе никаких массивов (`Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");`), и дополнительный комментарий (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) не выходит вместе с ошибкой. Ещё раз: любая программа выходит с этой ошибкой